Google Earth Engine (GEE): How to "loop" through MultiPolygon object by ID
I am somewhat new to GEE and am trying to clip and export tiff files for each of my study regions. My var "BBS_Routes" is a multi-polygon with 250 separate polygons, each with a unique ID number as indexed by 'RTENO'. Ideally I would like to be able to load in the image collection "LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_B_002_MONTHLY", clip it to each separate polygon and export with a unique name based on 'RTENO'.
In R, I would perform a "for loop", but I am unsure how to use ".map" or another function to achieve this in GEE. Any thoughts are appreciated!
// Area of interest: Define by geometry of BBS Route(s)
// Select Single BBS Route to test 

// var AOI_Geom = BBS_Routes.first().geometry();
var AOI_Geom = BBS_Routes.filter(ee.Filter.eq('RTENO', 2021));

// Study period.
var startYear_Num = 2016;
var endYear_Num = 2023;

// GEDI Level-2B data located within the AOI and
//   collected during the study period.
var studyPeriod_AOI_Filter = ee.Filter.and(
  // Filter by geometry 
  ee.Filter.bounds(AOI_Geom),
  
  // filter by year
  ee.Filter.calendarRange({
    start: startYear_Num, 
    end: endYear_Num, 
    field: "year"
  })
);


// Create a object of filtered GEDI L2B --------
var L2B_IC = ee.ImageCollection(
  "LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_B_002_MONTHLY")
  .filter(studyPeriod_AOI_Filter).select('pavd.*');
  
 
var HtSt_PAVD = L2B_IC
  .median().multiply(5).clip(AOI_Geom).toFloat();


// TEST: MAPING TO SEE IF IT WORKS
print(HtSt_PAVD)

Map.addLayer(AOI_Geom, 
    {
      color: "FF0000"
    }, 
    "AOI_Geom");
    
 Map.addLayer(HtSt_PAVD.select("pavd_z0"),
    {
      min: 0,
      max: 3,
      palette: ["0000FF", "FFFFFF", "FF0000"]
    }, 
    "HtSt_PAVD_clipped");



 // Export to base Google Drive  ----------------------------------
   var prj_25m = {
     crs: "EPSG:4326",
     scale: 25
   };
   
     Export.image.toDrive({ image: HtSt_PAVD , 
     description: 'exportToDrive', 
     fileNamePrefix: 'HtSt_PAVD',
     folder: 'GEDI_Export',
     region: AOI_Geom.bounds(),
     scale: prj_25m.scale,
     crs: prj_25m.crs,
     maxPixels: 1e13,
     skipEmptyTiles: true
     });

 


I was able to figure it out using a for loop structure. It works but there is probably a more efficient way to do it.  I used this for loop structure as a wrapper: "for(var i=0; i<250; i++){}" and then indexed by RTENO.: "var AOI_Geom = BBS_Routes.filter(ee.Filter.eq('RTENO', RTENOs.get(i) ));"
